# Printing tag in Jekyll prints entire post and other problems

Tags: arrays, loops, jekyll

So basically I'm having [**this problem**](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/129#issuecomment-61212460). I want to print the categories name as a heading, but categories with several words haven't work so far with anything I've tried, so I've solved it setting a tag and a category in every post.

So after this decision, I tested 2 tags and 2 categories, `tag1` for `cat1` and `tag2` for `cat2`, where every tag has a correspondent category. Then I added those tag/cat pairs to some of my posts. My algorithm looks like this:

```
for loop in tags

    print category in a heading tag

        for loop in posts of that category

            print some post info
```

which, translated into code, looks like this:

```
{% assign i = 0 %}
{% for TAG in site.tags %}
    <p>Checking the i: {{ i }}</p> 
    <p>Checking the tag: {{ TAG }}</p> 
    <h1>Checking the cat: {{ site.categories[i] }}</h1> 

    {% for post in site.tags.TAG %}
        <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    {% assign i = i + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

And the output is:

```
Checking the i: 0
Checking the tag: tag1
THE WHOLE POST
Checking the cat: (nothing is printed here)

Checking the i: 0
Checking the tag: 0
Checking the cat: (nothing is printed here)
```

And then it stops.

So my questions are:

- How to access the category? Right now it prints nothing
- Why does it print the WHOLE post contents after the tag?
- Why does it print one tag only?
- Why isn't the `i` incremented at the end of the loop?

Answer (score 1):

### How to access the category? Right now it prints nothing

Site categories is a hash :

```
Hash
{"github issue"=>[#Jekyll:Post, #Jekyll:Post],
 "toto"=>[#Jekyll:Post, #Jekyll:Post],
 "jekyll"=>[#Jekyll:Post]}
```

`site.categories['github issue']` return a post array
`site.categories[0]` return an empty array

### Why does it print the WHOLE post contents after the tag?

Same reason as above in the `{% for TAG in site.tags %}`, TAG is a hash an what you see is the string representation of this hash. If you have two post in this tag, you will see two post when you print TAG.

To get the tag name from here : `{{TAG.first}}`

### Why does it print one tag only?

It prints two tags

```
Checking the i: 0
Checking the tag: tag1
THE WHOLE POST
Checking the cat: (nothing is printed here)

Checking the i: 0
Checking the tag: 0
Checking the cat: (nothing is printed here)
```

This behavior is clearly unpredictable mainly because you've declared tags and categories in your `_config.yml`. You are not supposed to do that because `site.tags` and `site.categories` are set by Jekyll at generation time depending on tags and categories found in your posts. Remove this from your config and only set you tags in [default front matter config](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#front-matter-defaults) or in posts.

### Why isn't the i incremented at the end of the loop?

```
{% assign i = i | plus: 1 %}
```

See [liquid documentation](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/math-filters#plus)

### Possible solution

```
{% for tag in site.tags %}
  {% assign tagName = tag.first %}
  <h1>{{ tagName }}</h1>
    {% for category in site.categories %}
    <h2>{{ category.first }}</h2>
        {% for post in site.posts %}
          {% if post.tags contains tagName %}
              <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer really dissipated a lot of confusion. So it looks like "`TAG in site.tags`" behaves the same as `site.tags.TAG`? That is, it returns an array of posts under that `TAG`? Also, in your solution, the loop in posts is dissociated from the loop in categories, so for each tag, it prints all the categories available, then prints the same posts under different categories for the same tag. I only want the category associated with the tag. (Continues in next comment >>)

Comment: (<< from previous comment) But your example helped me realize something else: if Jekyll is taking the tags and cats from posts, they will be saved in the array in any order (alphabetical, I guess), so they won't necessarily be placed at the same index in each array for every case. I guess I'll have to print the titles manually and then do a simple loop for that tag. Right now I can't think of any way to keep the pair (tag, cat) related :(